# D3.js Chart Random Data or Weather API

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, d3.js

*[Solution found thanks to Gerardo Furtado]

I am new to coding and am currently working on a project for a solar/wind energy forecast. In my design I need a chart showing the predicted Kilowatt generation forecast for the coming week. I have been trying to figure out how to connect data from the Dark Sky API to the following chart based on the tutorial found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). I am now trying to replace the frequency data values with randomly generated numbers as dummy data but can't figure out how to do so. Any suggestions on how to approach this? Thank you.

index.html:

```
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatPercent = d3.format("0");

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(formatPercent);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Predicted KW Total:</strong> <span style='color:#FFD15B'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
      })


    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Kilowatts (KW)");

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

    });

    d3.select("#chart").attr("align","center");

    function type(d) {
      d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      return d;
    }
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

#chart {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 float:left;
 width: 80%;
 height: 550px;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.light {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #717070;
}

.tagline {
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin-top: 4px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

bod {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar:hover {
 fill: #FFD15B;
}

.x.axis path {
 display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 12px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.d3-tip:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline;
font-size: 10px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
content: "\25BC";
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

.d3-tip.n:after {
 margin: -1px 0 0 0;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
}

.axis text {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
    fill: #D47039;
}

.x.axis path {
 display: none;
}

label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

data.tsv:

```
letter  frequency
Sun 10
Mon 20
Tues 5
Wed 10
Thurs 30
Fri 15
Sat 8
```

Comment: Why don't you drop that TSV and use `Math.random()`?

Comment: I have tried that and can't figure out how to replace the TSV without breaking the code.

Comment: Any ideas on how to add math.random()?

Comment: You just need 7 random values to the bars, is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to replace that TSV with random values, create an array with the days:

```
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
```

And create your own `data` array based on `days`:

```
var data = [];

days.forEach(function(d) {
    data.push({
        letter: d,
        frequency: ~~(Math.random() * 30)
    })
})
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];

var data = [];

days.forEach(function(d) {
  data.push({
    letter: d,
    frequency: ~~(Math.random() * 30)
  })
})

var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format("0");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Predicted KW Total:</strong> <span style='color:#FFD15B'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
  })


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);


x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Kilowatts (KW)");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

```css
.light {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #717070;
}

.tagline {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

bod {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: #FFD15B;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: #D47039;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!